# Deploying first app to Heroku: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I am trying to deploy an Express/React/Mongo app to Heroku for the first time.

It is failing with a 503 error. The logs states the following:

> Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within
>   60 seconds of launch

I have set the following port variable in the root index.js file:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
```

and use it here:

```
app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("Express server is running on port " + port)
})
```

It outputs "Express server is running on port 3000", which suggest that it is not picking up the Environmental variable.

I have been trying to follow instructions here: https://coursework.vschool.io/deploying-mern-with-heroku/

The key part that I am may be misunderstanding:

> With Heroku, you need to set the environment variables on your newly
>   created Heroku app so it knows which values to use when the project is
>   deployed. You can do this two ways, either online on Heroku's website,
>   or through the command line using the heroku CLI. Since we are not
>   creating a new Heroku remote repository, all environment variables
>   will need to be added using Heroku.com.

I took this to mean that I should set an environmental variable Heroku.com, which I believe I have done so:

[image]

What am I failing to grok?

EDIT: I have tried setting theprocess.env.PORT=8000 from the Heroku CLI:

```
heroku config:set process.env.PORT=8000
```

But get the following error:

> »   Error: Missing required flag:  »     -a, --app APP  app to run
>   command against  »   See more help with --help

Here is the full index.js:

```
const express = require('express'),
    cors = require('cors'),
    app = express(),
    port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    todoRoutes = require('./routes/todo'),
    path = require("path");


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build")))

app.get('/', function (req, res){
    res.send('Root route')
})

app.use('/api/todos', todoRoutes);

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
});

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("Express server is running on port " + port)
})
```

Comment: You don't need to set the environment variable for the port in heroku.

Comment: can you share your index.js here to have a better look at it ?

Comment: I know this is kind of grave-digging, but for anyone strolling by, you don't need `process.env` in your environment variable names, just the variable, ie `PORT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had local dev server running whilst deploying to Heroku. Tried redeploying after stopping dev server, and it worked. Local servers interfered with environment variables in deployment.

Comment: you saved the day! I went through dozens of issues/questions and this was the one which resolved my issue, thanks!

Comment: What exactly did you mean by 'local' dev server? did you mean some local dev server on your PC? How my local dev version on PC can interfere to heroku servers?